# How to logout from facebook Programatically android?

Tags: android, facebook

i making an  social app, i have integrated `facebook` login but, when i logout from it, it not getting logout permanently , & when trying to login again it, automatically login again from the previous id.

Following is my code

```
LoginManger.getInstance().logOut();
```

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: why problematically ?

Comment: i guess he ment programatically :D

Comment: post full code...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 sir this is only code which i am using to logout...  if you can suggest more i will be thankful to you..

Comment: what version of the sdk are you using?

Comment: @BernardParah Facebook SDK 4.0

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to keep any session data, simply call [closeAndClearTokenInformation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Session/#closeAndClearTokenInformation%28%29) when your app closes.Else if you are using facebook sdk if you try to login again it will ask you to logout first.

Comment: sir problem is that i am unable to logout of facebook...  if can do this first than i can perform this too..

Answer (score 0):

Adding the first line below should make it work

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());       
 LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```